# Datamaps.js access default projection and change it

Tags: d3.js, datamaps

I would like to use Datamaps.js in a similar way as Google Charts in order to select some regions around the world.

Firstly, I would like to access the default "**setProjection**" function, but I do not know how.

Then, I would like to create **projections** in several regions around the world.
However, I have seen only the Africa example in the [Datamaps](http://datamaps.github.io/) web

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

What I am currently testing is this code. It surely could be improved, but it works:

```
    function getProjection() {
  //Projection por defecto
  var currentProjection;
  var region = $("#mapRegions")[0].value;

  if (region === 0) {
    // Zoom in on World
    currentProjection = function(element) {
      var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
        .center([0, 20])
        .rotate([-10, 0])
        .scale(65)
        .translate([element.offsetWidth / 2, element.offsetHeight / 2]);
      var path = d3.geo.path()
        .projection(projection);

      return {
        path: path,
        projection: projection
      };
    }
  } else if (region == 1) {
    // Zoom in on Africa
    currentProjection = function(element) {
      var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
        .center([23, 5])
        .rotate([4.4, 0])
        .scale(150)
        .translate([element.offsetWidth / 2, element.offsetHeight / 2]);
      var path = d3.geo.path()
        .projection(projection);

      return {
        path: path,
        projection: projection
      };
    }
  } else if (region == 2) {
    // Zoom in on Europa
    currentProjection = function(element) {
      var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
        .center([45, 60])
        .rotate([0, 0])
        .scale(150)
        .translate([element.offsetWidth / 2, element.offsetHeight / 2]);
      var path = d3.geo.path()
        .projection(projection);

      return {
        path: path,
        projection: projection
      };
    }
  }
  return currentProjection;
}
```

The key was to **change the d3.geo projection,** as I am currently working with Mercator.

Comment: Show us some code of yourself.

Comment: With DataMaps, you can create multiple maps with different projections, but you can't currently update an existing map with a new projection. Which one of those are you looking for?

Comment: Hello Mark, the idea was initially to zoom in on the map presenting different regions around the world, similar to the regions available in Google Charts. For the moment, I will recreate the object with the projection set to that specific area...I will also try to use this: map.svg.selectAll("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")"); with the proper values instead of recreating a new Datamap when the region is selected.